# How to measure the rotation direction and speed of a ring on a finger?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, distance-measurement

I am trying to create a device that can measure the rotation of a ring on a finger. Basically there's going to be two rings on the finger, one that rotates and one that is stationary. The idea is that the stationary (or rotating ring, if that's an option) will be able to measure how much it's rotated relative to the stationary ring.

I obviously can't have anything in the center of rotation so there has to be some other option. I had the idea of making my own potentiometer which might be possible but I was wondering if there are any other options.

My idea for the project is to rotate the ring with a string attached to another finger, that way getting an idea for how far away the finger is from the ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have 3 magnets on one, irregularly spaced which will show rotation.

Then Hall effect sensors on the other, as the signals are recorded the relative spacing shows rotation and even direction.

Comment: How accurate do you think that this method will be?

Comment: Well a magnetised nut allowed the rpm of a turbocharger to be recorded about 170000 rpm, but don't think you will need that range...